Trigger indexer using Azure data factory
I am using delete activity inside a foreach activity to delete a list of files from ADLS container. Now after deletion of the files. I want to execute the indexer so that my index points to the updated content. How can I achieve this through ADF or any custom solution for this.
I want to execute an indexer after deletion of every file.

'I want to execute the indexer so that my index points to the updated content' - What operation are you doing in this indexer? can you explain this with an example?

I wanted to run the indexer so that the deleted file reference is removed and index is updated. I am achieving this using web activity where in url I'm passing "https://.search.windows.net/indexers//run?api-version=2020-06-30" and in headers api-key i.e. your search service key.

Are the indexer names different for every file or same? If different, Do you have indexer names list? Can you provide that?

Indexer name is same. Can you tell me after deletion the indexer should be reset and then run or re-run will itself show the deletechanges?

there is no acitivity for azure ai search. So,you need to use rest api to reset and run the indexer.
Add 2 web activity after your foreach activity so that after every update you can reset it and run.

Below are the configuration.
Indexer reset
URL :  https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexers/[indexer name]/reset?api-version=[api-version]
Method :  POST
Body: {"body":"none"}
Authentication: None
Headers :

Content-Type:  application/json 
api-key :  Your api key

Second   Indexer re-run
URL :  https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexers/[indexer name]/run?api-version=[api-version]
Method :  POST
Body: {"body":"none"}
Authentication: None
Headers :

Content-Type:  application/json 
api-key :  Your api key

Output:


Without resetting the indexer it won't reflect the changes?

You need to reset and re-run it

Index still has the reference of the deleted documents. It is showing same document count

try re-creating new index

The azure Ai search documentation addresses this problem here
from the documentation:

An indexer doesn't track object deletion in data sources. To avoid
having orphan search documents, you can implement a "soft delete"
strategy that results in deleting search documents first, with
physical deletion in Azure Storage following as a second step.
There are two ways to implement a soft delete strategy:
Native blob soft delete, applies to Blob Storage only Soft delete
using custom metadata

These are also available when creating via Azure portal

